# Dúvida de como submeter um form em JSF usando <p:confirmDialog>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Queria saber como eu faço para enviar um Form usando o `p:comfirmdialog`.

A ideia é aparecer a mensagem `tem certeza ?`, com as opções `sim` ou `não`. Se clicar em `sim`, então ele envia o Form.

```
 <p:commandButton value="destruir o mundo" >
    <p:confirm header="confirmação" message="tem certeza ?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" Effect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="sim" type="submit"  icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"  icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

esses comandos já estão dentro do form, ai eu queria, que quando confirmasse o formulário fosse enviado.

já tentei mudar o type para 'button', ja deixei sem type e nada.

Obrigado a todos que ajudarem

Comment: Poste o seu código para melhor ajudá-lo.

Comment: Votei por reabrir, pois acredito que sou capaz de fornecer um exemplo, mesmo sem ter muito conhecimento do PrimeFaces. Acredito que tenha sido precipitado ao fechar, mas tudo que é fechado pode ser reaberto :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Dei meu voto para reabrir esta pergunta. Poderia ajudar a reabrir [esta outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93392/132)?

Comment: Boa noite, a resposta lhe resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a documentação http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml o uso seria algo como:

O xhtml ficaria assim:

```
<h:form>           
    <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />

    <p:commandButton value="Chamar o evento" actionListener="#{dialogView.meuEvento}" update="message">
        <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Você está certo disto?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

E o java:

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.overlay;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.CloseEvent;

@ManagedBean
public class DialogView
{ 
    public void meuEvento()
    {
        addMessage("System Error", "Por favor tente novamente");
    }

    public void addMessage(String summary, String detail)
    {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, detail);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

O método `meuEvento` acredito ser o que irá salvar os dados.

Answer (score 0):

coloca assim

```
<p:commandLink action="">
    <p:confirm header="" message="" />
</p:commandLink>
```